# Multiple Problems with Django SocialAuth - logging in with facebook, yahoo, google

Tags: django, facebook, yahoo, google-account, django-socialauth

I am having some problems with the app django socialauth.

I am receiving the following errors:

```
no such table: openid_consumer_association
```

I got the above error whenever I click on the google or Yahoo icon for logging in.
may I know how do i fix this problem?

Another error I am receiving is related to facebook connect. Whenever i try to access the facebook login url at http://localhost:8000/accounts/facebook_login/, I receive the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Missing client_id"
   }
}
```

I've been searching high and low for a successful implementation of socialauth.

But it seems that there is quite a bit of bugs?

Any tips, suggestions are more than welcomed!

Comment: Have your run `python manage.py syncdb` after installing your app?

Comment: yup. I did that. but i kept receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put those in your settings

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = ''
FACEBOOK_API_KEY = ''
FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY = ''
```

get those id & keys from http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php

Answer (score 1):

For the Google and Yahoo buttons, the socialauth login page fails because (I'm guessing here, but it does the same for mine) you don't have the authentication backend enabled for OpenID support. Once you do this, and of course, fill in the other OpenID-required elements, you should have working links.